# Replace one div with another

Tags: jquery, html, css

Have 2 divs.

Here is code

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
    <video id="preview" controls style="border: 1px solid rgb(15, 158, 238); height: 280px; width: 300px;" muted="muted" ;></video>
</p>


<input type="button" id="record" class="btn btn-default" style="background: #ffcf00; color: black; height: 40px;text-shadow: none" value="Запись" onclick="doTimer()"/>
<button id="stop"  class="btn btn-default" style="background: #ffcf00; color: black; height: 40px;text-shadow: none" disabled>Остановить</button>
<div id="container" style="padding:1em 2em;"></div>
```

I need to replace preview with container

I wrote this

```
 $('#preview').replaceWith('#container');
```

But it just paste word container instead of div

Where is mistake?

Comment: `$('#preview').replaceWith($('#container').html());`

Answer (score 2):

You are now appending the string `#container` you need to actually get the html of that selector using `html()` method, so your code should be:

```
$('#preview').replaceWith($('#container').html());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some error in your `jquery code` you can use following code for this

```
$( "#preview" ).replaceWith($("#container"));
```

Comment: Thank's so much dude!!